# SQL how to query average run time

Tags: sql, time, average

I've searched and they said that you can't use AVG(time/date). What I'm trying to do is to query and get the average run time. For example:

Table1

```
Runner Name    | Run Time (minutes:seconds)  
Jack           | 1:20  
Jack           | 1:22  
Jack           | 1:18  
Paul           | 1:19  
Paul           | 1:24  
Paul           | 1:17  
Troy           | 1:30  
Troy           | 1:40  
Troy           | 1:35
```

Results:

```
Runner Name    | Average Run Time  
Jack           | 1:20  
Paul           | 1:20  
Troy           | 1:35
```

I have tried several queries such as `Cast(AVG(CAST...`
and `Round(Unix_timestamp(...`

Comment: What's the database and what data type each column is?

Comment: SQL database (table1) and not sure what the data type is, but the column is called "runtime" and the data are shown in time format, like the above description.

Comment: "SQL" is just a language to query databases, not the database engine itself. Can you point out the database?

Comment: Um I'm not sure what the database or type it is then. Sorry

Comment: I believe they are mysql databases.

Comment: What is "SQL database"???

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Runtime is varchar, not time.  Otherwise it should 00:01:20. The following is based on this assumption:

```
create table t1 (Runner varchar(64) not null,Runtime varchar(30) not null);

INSERT t1(Runner,Runtime)
VALUES('Jack','1:20'),('Jack','1:22'),('Jack','1:18'),
('Paul','1:19'),('Paul','1:24'),('Paul','1:17'),
('Troy','1:30'),('Troy','1:40'),('Troy','1:35');

SELECT Runner,CAST(AVG(CAST(CAST(CONCAT('00:',Runtime) AS time) AS unsigned)) AS time) AS AvgRunTime
FROM t1
GROUP BY Runner;
```

Comment: I'm doing it manually in excel and the results are different from it. And I am also getting some nulls, which when I do it in Excel, it doesn't get any nulls

Comment: casting a time to an unsiged -- that is not going to give you seconds.  I think the expectation is that we are averaging the number of seconds.

Comment: seconds still there. CAST to unsigned then cast back to time:  SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(CONCAT('00:',Runtime) AS time) AS unsigned) AS time) AS runtime
FROM t1

Answer (score 0):

Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator, so you can use this to get the average in seconds:

```
select Runner, avg(datediff(ss, 0, cast(concat("00:",Runtime) as time)))
from t1
group by Runner
```

Comment: Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: I just tested it. Runs fine on SQL Server 2017 14.0.2027.2. I have assumed that both Runner and Runtime are varchars.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code. Please adjust column and table names accordingly.

```
SELECT Runner_Name,
CAST(AVG(CAST(Run_Time AS TIME)) AS TIME) 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Runner_Name
```

Comment: Your query is similar to the previous one. It's giving me some nulls for the average and when I do it manually in Excel, it does not have any nulls.

Comment: Do you have any Null value in that column?

Comment: No Null values in that column

Comment: I am getting all fine. You can check fiddle here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f7c64dae81e60d34335c66306a2d6d4